# Not showing picture with handlebars

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, handlebars.js

I want to show the picture by using handlebars but it doesn't show it in a right way like the below picture:

[image]

I used this code:

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each list}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{Index}}</td>
        <td>{{Name}}</td>
        <td>{{Email}}</td>
        <td>{{Subject}}</td>
        <td>{{BodyMsg}}</td>

        <td><img {{bind-attr src="Imageurl"}} /></td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Comment: Please add `list`'s value

Comment: Also add your JavaScript code where you use that template.

Comment: Do you need something like that http://jsbin.com/qanahetero/edit?html,css,js,output ? It works, as I can see, without `bind-attr`.

Answer (score 0):

`bind-attr` is [`Ember`](http://emberjs.com/)-specific syntax. You don't need to use it with `handlebars`.

```js
var source = $("#entry-template").html(); 
var template = Handlebars.compile(source); 

var list = [{
    Index: 1, 
    Name: 'John',
    Email: 'Smith',
    Subject: 'Why Ember?',
    BodyMsg: 'Something very important',
    Imageurl: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdW0i.jpg'
    }
]; 

$('body').append(template({list: list}));
```

```css
body {
    font:15px arial,sans-serif;
}
h1 {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 24px;
    background-color: #999;
    color: #fff;
}
table {
    margin: 10px;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
th {
    background: #ccc;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #eee;
}
td a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>       
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.0.0/handlebars.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each list}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{Index}}</td>
            <td>{{Name}}</td>
            <td>{{Email}}</td>
            <td>{{Subject}}</td>
            <td>{{BodyMsg}}</td>

            <td>
                <img src="{{Imageurl}}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
</script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is `bind-attr`.

Try replacing with this:

```
<td><img src={{Imageurl}} /></td>
```